# Animate background image javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve a background animate image, that moves from right to left, but the image won´t animate, could you help me verify my code?

```
<body>
   <div id="background-container"></div>

    <script> type="text/javascipt">
        function animateBackground(elem, speed) {
          var x = 0 ;
          var y = -50;

        elem.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px';

        var timer = setInterval (function(speed) {
        elem.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px';
        x--;
        if (x == -600) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              }
        },speed)
  }

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", animateBackground(document.getElementById('background-container'), 15), false); 
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite ugly but actually it looks fine. What is definitely wrong is how you are adding the event handler. Instead of adding a handler function, you *call* your handler function inline, so it actually doesn't add any listener. You should pass the `function` itself, for example like this, using an anonymous function inline.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { animateBackground(document.getElementById('background-container'), 15); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have provided a jsfiddle link, which would have made it easy. By the way here is the working jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/4o88z0tt/

I added a css background to the div tag using

```
div{
    background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Rest assured, I didn't do any changes to your js code or the html code. It worked fine for me.